# Getting output for inches

Tags: c++, unit-conversion

Below is a code I wrote to convert user input of inches to miles, yards, feet. My only issue is that the format in which I would like this to be output would require the output to have "0 inches" as well.

For the life of me I cannot figure that much out. I tried setting a new int value to inches and have it return 0, but that just confused things even more.

Thanks for any help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int
main ()
{


  double m;
  double y;
  double f;
  double i;

  cout << " Enter the Length in inches:";
  cin >> i;

  m = i / 63360;        // Convert To Miles
  y = 1760 * m;         // Convert To Yards
  f = 3 * y;            // Convert to Feet
  i = 12 * f;           // Convert to Inches

  cout << i << "inches =" << " " << m << " " << "(mile)s," << " " <<
  y << " " << "yards," << " " << f << " " << "feet," << " " << i <<
    " " << "inches." << endl;



  return 0;
```

Comment: The question is really unclear. Tell me one thing, you have inches from user input then why are you calculating it again?

Comment: It is for a project, and the specifics for output are as follows,   Enter the number of inches: 12300000
12300000 inches = 194 miles, 226 yards, 2 ft, 0 in.

Comment: i may be taking things very literal, but I thought I would ask better minds than me to see if there was a way to have the output mirror that.

Comment: Your code isn't calculating anything close to your desired output. Think about how you're figuring out this answer by hand, then duplicate that method in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you want the calculation to cascade such as it takes inches and roles it up to the biggest units possible.  So 15" would go to 1' 3".  If my guess is wrong ignore this answer.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static const int INCHES_PER_MILE =  63360;
static const int INCHES_PER_YARD =  36;
static const int INCHES_PER_FOOT =  12;

int main ()
{
     int inches, m, y, f ,i, remainder; //int so that we dont get decimal values

     cout << " Enter the Length in inches:";
     cin >> inches;

     m = inches / INCHES_PER_MILE ;             // Convert To Miles  -- shouldn't be 'magic numbers'
     remainder= inches % INCHES_PER_MILE ;      // % stands for modulo -- (i.e. take the remainder)
     y = remainder / INCHES_PER_YARD;        // Convert To Yards
     remainder = remainder % INCHES_PER_YARD;
     f = remainder / INCHES_PER_FOOT;        // Convert to Feet
     remainder = remainder % INCHES_PER_FOOT;
     i = remainder;             // Convert to Inches

     cout << inches << " inches = " << m <<" (mile)s, " <<
     y << " yards, " << f << " feet, " << i << " inches." << endl;

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You probably want to fix your magic numbers to.  Its just a good practice to not have them.

Comment: I'm pretty new to programming so not plugging in number to the source code is hard. I had a quick question as well. When I ran the above code it prints as expected except for the first line. When the output comes it reads: 10 inches = 71 (mile)s, 1302 yards, 1 feet, 10 inches.  Now is there something in the remainder part I can change? If not I may just fiddle around with this until I figure it out. Again thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah I missed that.  Fixed now.  Can't use i in both spots.

Comment: ***static const int INCHES_PER_FOOT =  36;*** That is a large foot..

Comment: Nice catch @drescherjm. I was trying to add "inches" in different places myself. Feels like im finally learning/retaining coding information! Thanks again.

Comment: My bad missed that. :P

Answer (score 2):

This is probably closer to what you want:

```
// ...

int m;
int y;
int f;
int i;
int len;

cout << " Enter the Length in inches:";
cin >> len;

cout << len << "inches = ";

m = len / 63360;        // Miles
len -= m * 63360;
y = len / 36;           // Yards
len -= y * 36;
f = len / 12;           // Feet
i = len % 12;           // Inches

if (m)
    cout << m << " (mile)s, ";
if (y)
    cout << y << " yards, "; 
if (f)
    cout << f << " feet, ";

cout << i << " inches." << endl;

// ...
```